# Is there a way to know if the retry was successful or not in the doAfterRetry method in Spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

yThe failure attribute of the RetrySignal seems to hold the original exception, and is not cleared upon successful retry. Is success at all possible to detect in this method or is there another way?

Logging the failure() shows that is stil present after a successful retry

```
 .doAfterRetry  {
      if (it.failure() == null)  {. // never happens
          log.info("Retry OK")
      }
      else {
          log.warn("Retry failed")
      }
  }
```

Comment: Some code could be useful to understand the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.